# Escape HTML tags in Jekyll

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I'm using Jekyll for github pages site. There are several blocks of code to be shown in `<pre>` block and included in demo page as working code. For this purpose I've extracted these blocks in **_includes**.

Lets say, we have **basic.html** in **_includes** folder.

Now I'm including it on demo page as working code:

```
{% include demos/basic.html %}
```

And I need to include this code in `<pre>` tag.

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-html">{% include demos/basic.html %}</pre>
```

Here I have issue with HTML tags inside `<pre>`. They should be escaped. I found `xml_escape` filter in Jekyll but it cannot be applied to includes.

Could anybody advice me how to cope with this?

Comment: Could anybody explain me why my question is downvoted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, found the solution. We can [capture the include in variable](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1303) and then apply our filter.

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-js">
    {% capture my_include %}{% include demos/basic.html %}{% endcapture %}
    {{ my_include | xml_escape }}</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks! Been looking to do this for ages!