# Jekyll escapes closing html tags

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I want to create a publication list using the following Jekyll code:

```
<div class="publications">
  {% assign sorted_pubs = site.publications | sort: "date" %}
  <ol>
    {% for pub in sorted_pubs %}
      <li> {% include pubformat.html %} </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ol>
</div>
```

The problem is that Jekyll escapes the closing tags `</li>`, `</ol>`, and `</div>`. That is, Jekyll creates an html file with  `&lt;/li&gt;`,  `&lt;/ol&gt;` and  `&lt;/div&gt;`, respectively, instead of the html tags. This happens if the code sits in a `.md` file or a `.html` file (in `_includes`). How can I prevent this?

I found many similar questions on this site, but none had a solution (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27473762) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59880835) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43961376)).

Comment: Can you give a clearer example of what exactly that means?

Comment: @deceze I edited the question. Is this clearer?

Comment: It leaves the *opening* tags alone?!

Comment: yes indeed.   ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Can you include the content of `pubformat.html`? What file is the list code posted in? Any chance you could provide a GitHub repo link as well?